# Does adding meta-information suffice for including myself as additional @author of a class?

Tags: java, jpa, javadoc

Me and my colleague are in the process of developing domain model for a small part of our project. Recently he committed skeleton entity classes to our SVN repository without adding JPA annotations. At the same time I have designed physical data model and created corresponding database objects. Now I need to map the entity classes to the database, making various decisions about *inheritance strategies* and other things. Does annotating classes qualify me as additional `@author`? I know that typically, additional `@author` tag could be added when some crucial changes had been made to the class. But what if I provide only meta-information?

**Edit:**
It's not about ego. It's about whether it's common and considered a good practice.
Some say @author tags are useless, since the code is under *version control* anyway.
But I personally don't think so. This tag could be quite useful in some cases.

Comment: I didn't know there were any "qualifications". Or that anybody actually used the tag for anything particular, since file modification info in the SCCS already tells who has modified the file. In any case, the answer to this question is totally arbitrary and depends on your organization.

Comment: Does editing the `@author` suffice for including myself as additional `@author` of a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always add @author to classes I make substantial contributions too.  I run into many instances where a colleague has created the skeletons, or something not complete, where I added myself as an @author as well.

To me, it's not about ego, but more so a quick reference for someone else who has to look at the file without them having to go back through version control logs if they need information.

Comment: Totally agree with you. I think it's really important to keep the @author list up-to-date, so you would quickly find out what person to contact in case you have questions. Analyzing SVN could take much longer, especially if a class has big history.

Answer (score 1):

Don't let egos get in the way of software.  Do you really care?

Anyway, designing the JPA annotations, hierarchies, and related code is much more difficult than creating skeleton entities, so if you really care, then add it.

Note that your VCS will keep track of who is contributing what work, so there will always be a single point of truth for who put what code where in the app.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it's ok to add yourself as `@author`. Configuring JPA annotations may not be that easy. If you are not sure ask your colleague. Having a SVN (and separate accounts) it's easy to find out who made what.

Comment: As hvgotcodes wrote: do you really care? I'd prefer collective code ownership instead of author tagging.